# MySQL: Operations with the TIME datatype

Tags: mysql, time

Suppose I have a table like that:

```
create table reserved (
    id int(4) primary key,
    name varchar(30),
    quantity int(4),
    price int(8),
    info varchar(50),
    expiration_time time,
    contract_id varchar(50)
);
```

And I insert a few rows in it, using the format "HH:MM:SS" for the expiration_time field.
Now I want to update this field, by adding 50 seconds:

```
update reserved set expiration_date=expiration_date+50 where id=1
```

When I have HH:MM and less than 10 seconds for the SS, everything works fine. But for a time like: 01:10:40, adding 50 seconds would result in 01:11:00 . What can i do to fix this behavior? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ADDTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) together with [`MAKETIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_maketime):

```
UPDATE reserved
SET expiration_date=ADDTIME(expiration_date,MAKETIME(0,0,50))
WHERE id=1;
```

Comment: how would I calculate if a TIME is after another TIME? is the ">" operator ok?

Comment: @Madrugada: Why don't you try it and see?  ;)